# Apache redirection based on URL from the same webserver

Tags: apache, api, redirect, zabbix

We needed to implement SSL for our Zabbix monitoring frontend and it's caused havok on some of our backend scripting (which would be more trouble than it's worth to fix).

I'm currently working under the theory that I should be able to use some redirection magic in order to:

- Access our normal Zabbix Frontend via HTTPS
- Access our API via HTTP (this is the key hangup right now).

Initially - redirection was easy enough:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName <servername>
RedirectMatch /zabbix/(.*) https://<servername>/zabbix/$1
</VirtualHost>
```

But this causes all sorts of issues with our API calls needing to still be done via HTTP (which is being done via a scripts calling API values to drive interface selections in other tools). I actually end up getting a 412 response.

So I thought I could maybe do something like this:

```
RedirectMatch /zabbix/(!api_jsonrpc.php)(.*) https://<servername>/zabbix/$2
```

While this will still let my API succeed over HTTP, it doesn't redirect my zabbix frontend to HTTPS.

This has been driving me nuts! Any help would be appreciated.

Sample URLS:

```
https://<servername>/zabbix/zabbix.php?action=dashboard.view
https://<servername>/zabbix/index.php
http://<servername>/zabbix/api_jsonrpc.php
```

Ultimately - anything that isn't "api_jsonrpc.php" needs redirected to HTTPS, and anything with that value needs to go over HTTP.

We are using Apache 2.2 and upgrading is not currently an option.

Comment: I'm just curious: why do you want to sacrifice https for API? What's that problem? Cross-site requests, self-signed cert, custom CA, ...?

Comment: It's a self-sign cert through our internal CA. 

It's more like cross-script processing that handles a lot of our automation.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, the issue I was having was coming down to the fact that you can't really redirect POSTs.

To resolve this, I ended up winning my argument that he library file update (forcing all traffic over HTTPS) and mass push was the only working solution and we're now golden.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot negate strings just by prefixing them with an exclamation mark, lookarounds would have to be used.

I don't think API requests pass any `GET` parameters - try the following:

```
RedirectMatch /zabbix/(.*)(?<!api_jsonrpc\.php)$ https://<servername>/zabbix/$1
```

Comment: Thanks for that - I'll have to play around with that configuration in the future.

Comment: Oh damn, I totally missed the fact that POST redirects are not there, save for HTTP code 307. That makes my answer incorrect, but I'll leave it up in case it is useful in a different scenario.

Comment: So, out of curiosity today, I tried your redirectmatch regex string. I pushed our library updates last week and forced redirected our entire server, but ultimately that pointed another hole in our system with the certs needing to be added to our java application (Rundeck) - which triggered the ask of me to take another crack at redirecting.

Through an act of magic we still don't understand, your redirect regex worked like a charm! I can no redirect all our monitoring frontends to SSL and our backend functions will still operate over port 80. Super weird, but functional.